# How to change the webservers ip address for a specific website in firefox?

Tags: firefox, dns, firefox-addon

for webdev purposes, especially in the phase where websites gets moved from one to another server it's nice to be able to keep the website as is on the old host and setup the system with the production domain on the new host. For this it's nice to change the ip resolution for my own computer for the specific domain to the new webervers ip address.

Up until now that worked by editing the hosts file on Windows 10 or to use a small external dns service like a pi-hole. However that doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there any nice plugin with which I can step into the dns resolution of firefox to provide a new ip address when a specific domain is requested?

Answer (score 0):

You can [turn off DNS-over-HTTPS](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https) and revert to traditional DNS lookup:

Manually enabling and disabling DNS-over-HTTPS

You can enable or disable DoH in your Firefox connection settings:

> 1. In the Menu bar at the top of the screen, click Firefox and select Preferences.
> 2. In the General panel, scroll down to Network Settings and click the Settings… button.
> 3. In the dialog box that opens, scroll down to Enable DNS over HTTPS and select "Off"
> 4. Click OK to save your changes and close the box.